# Подсказки в форме

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Что у меня есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<input name="dcity" placeholder="from" id="from" type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" >   
<input name="acity" placeholder="to" id="to" type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" >   

<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>

function showHint(str) {
if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Я ввожу первые буквы города и мне дает подсказку

```
$a[] = "Tbilisi";
$a[] = "Rome";
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $city) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($city, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $city;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $city";
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
```

я вот чего хочу я и не знаю как сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прощу помощи, очень нужно!

Comment: Приветствую. Сейчас ведь выводит подсказку по городу? Если да, то что нужно сделать?

Comment: Как я понял он хочет чтобы это было выпадающим списком а не отдельной строчкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

День добрый, если я Вас правильно понял, это называется autocomplete.
Вот решение [на Jquery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь)